# How can I calculate the sum of this series?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, symbolic, summation, backslide

**Backslide introduced after 9.0.1, persisting through 13.0.**

---

How can I calculate the sum of this series?

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \ln \left(1+\frac{1}{n^{2}}\right)$

The sum of this series has been proved to be convergent.

```
SumConvergence[Log[1 + 1/n^2], n]
```

> True

However, the results cannot be obtained with `Sum`.

```
Sum[Log[1 + 1/n^2], {n, 1, Infinity}]
```

> $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \log \left[1+\frac{1}{n^{2}}\right]$

Comment: `DiscreteLimit[Sum[Log[1 + 1/n^2], {n, 1, k}], k -> Infinity]` is running without any result in 13 on Windows during dozens minutes. Likely an infinite loop is formed as in many, many other commands of Mathematica.

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=series+Log%5B1+%2B+1%2Fn%5E2%5D+for+n+from+1+to+infinity is pretty close to N[Log[Sinh[Pi]/Pi]].

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Exponentiation followed by logarithm works, really fast:

```
Log@Product[1 + 1/n^2, {n, 1, Infinity}] // AbsoluteTiming
(*  {0.139728, Log[Sinh[π]/π]}  *)
```

Internal method works:

```
Sum`SumInfiniteLogarithmicSeries[
  Log[1 + 1/n^2], {n, 1, Infinity}] // FullSimplify
(*  Log[Sinh[π]/π  *)
```

Comment: FYI: `Sum[Log[1 + 1/n^2], {n, 1, Infinity}, Method -> Sum`SumInfiniteLogarithmicSeries]` calls the internal method that succeeds.

Comment: Awesome!!! I am not familiar with that way of performing the sums.

Comment: Wow, how did you find this? BTW, you can type \\` in comment to format the ` properly.

Comment: @xzczd I looked through the ``Sum` `` context, which I know from previous experience contains many methods.  I use a double backtick to format ``Sum[Log[1 + 1/n^2], {n, 1, Infinity}, Method -> Sum`SumInfiniteLogarithmicSeries]`` normally, but I forgot.

Comment: That's a great answer! By the way, how to  look through the Sum`  context? @Michael E2

Comment: @lotus2019 ``? Sum`*`` is one way. (~180 symbols).

Comment: @kcr Thanks. Another way to do the first method, although it is computationally a different path: `Limit[Log@FullSimplify[Exp@Sum[Log[1 + 1/n^2], {n, 1, k}]], k -> Infinity]` -- somehow it is overcautious about combining the logarithms. Perhaps it is the reason for the backslide. (Logs cannot be combined willy-nilly, but they can be combined in this case.)

Comment: @Michael E2 Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 6):

It's a backslide. *v9.0.1* handles the problem without difficulty:

[image]

Please report this to WRI.

---

One possible work-around for higher version (somewhat opportunistic):

```
sum = Sum[Log[1 + 1/n^2], {n, 1, nn}] // Simplify
(* I π - Log[-Gamma[2 - I]] - Log[Gamma[2 + I]] - 2 Log[Gamma[1 + nn]] + 
 Log[Gamma[(1 - I) + nn]] + Log[2 Gamma[(1 + I) + nn]] *)
```

There's a lot of `Log[…]` in `sum`, so we try

```
limit = Limit[E^sum, nn -> Infinity] // FullSimplify
(* Sinh[π]/π *)
```

It happens to succeed! So the original summation should be

```
Solve[E^Σ == limit, Σ, Reals] // Simplify
(* {{Σ -> Log[Sinh[π]/π]}} *)
```

Comment: (+1) and many thanks for spotting this backslide, but please have a look at the updated version of my answer as I get the answer as you did with `v9`.

Comment: @kcr (+1) Now it answers OP's question. :)

Comment: Thanks! It's weird, though, that there's a backslide in such an elementary sum. Nice catch!!!

Comment: Great! Thank you for your help! @xzczd

Answer (score 5):

Do it for a bunch of values

```
Table[Sum[Log[1 + 1/n^2], {n, 1, xx}], {xx, 1, 17}] // FullSimplify
```

> `{Log[2], Log[5/2], Log[25/9], Log[425/144], Log[221/72],  Log[8177/2592], Log[204425/63504], Log[13287625/4064256],  Log[544792625/164602368], Log[2200962205/658409472],  Log[134258694505/39833773056], Log[19467510703225/5736063320064],  Log[9791351537125/2868031660032],  Log[1928896252813625/562134205366272],  Log[8718611062717585/2529603924148224],  Log[2240683043118419345/647578604581945344],  Log[1124218135820660225/323789302290972672]}`

And now we are going to invoke a black box of Mathematica. Fingers crossed and hope it works

```
Log@FindSequenceFunction[{2, 5/2, 25/9, 425/144, 221/72, 8177/2592, 
204425/63504, 13287625/4064256, 544792625/164602368, 
2200962205/658409472, 134258694505/39833773056, 
19467510703225/5736063320064, 9791351537125/2868031660032, 
1928896252813625/562134205366272, 
8718611062717585/2529603924148224, 
2240683043118419345/647578604581945344, 
1124218135820660225/323789302290972672}, n] // FullSimplify
```

gives

> `Log[(Gamma[(1 - I) + n] Gamma[(1 + I) + n] Sinh[π])/(π Gamma[ 1 + n]^2)]`

Does this answer your question or did I misunderstood what you wanted?

Edit: a one-liner thanks to the comment by @AsukaMinato

```
Table[Sum[Log[1 + 1/n^2], {n, 1, xx}], {xx, 1, 17}] // FullSimplify // Map[First] // FindSequenceFunction // #[n]& // FullSimplify
```

Edit 2: I am addressing the issue that @xzczd had in the comments.

We can expand out the formula the `FindSequenceFunction` spat out

```
-2 Log[Gamma[1 + n]] + Log[Gamma[(1 - I) + n]] + 
 Log[Gamma[(1 + I) + n]] + Log[ Sinh[π]/π ]
```

Everything is a `Log` of something, so we can kill the `Log` and do the limit

```
Limit[Exp[-2 Log[Gamma[1 + n]] + Log[Gamma[(1 - I) + n]] + 
   Log[Gamma[(1 + I) + n]] + Log[ Sinh[\[Pi]]/\[Pi] ]], {n -> 
   Infinity}]
```

which yields

```
Sinh[π]/π
```

and the `Log` of the above is the answer to the original sum.

Comment: OP is summing to `Infinity`. If the upper index isn't `Infinity`, `Sum` can handle the problem without difficulty, no need to use `FindSequenceFunction`: `Sum[Log[1 + 1/n^2], {n, 1, nn}]`

Comment: one line `Table[Sum[Log[1 + 1/n^2], {n, 1, xx}], {xx, 1, 17}] // FullSimplify // Map[First] // FindSequenceFunction // #[n-1]& // FullSimplify`

Comment: @AsukaMinato a fine one-liner!!!

Comment: @xzczd as $n$ approaches higher and higher values you get `Log[something]`. `FindSequenceFunction` provides an analytic answer to that particular `[something]`. It's like doing a proof by induction

Comment: Very good method! Thank you! @kcr

Comment: Glad I helped :-) Please, have a look at the other excellent answers as well!!!